# Importing powershell code to .bat script

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I have a problem importing a powershell script into a batch script. Right now I am using the `powershell -Command "& { }"` to do this and I am seperating every line of powershell code with `;`. But I don't know what to do in order to import my `if` statement. This is an example of what I want to import:

```
If ($a -eq $false)
{
    "FALSE"
    exit
}
Else
{
    If ($b -eq $false)
    {
        "FALSE"
        exit
    }
}
```

Comment: You could save it as a PowerShell script and call it wìth `powershell.exe -File c:\myscript.ps1`, but considering you used the word `import`, I'm guessing you want a single file (if so, see answer).

Comment: Thanks for the reply @FrodeF. Yes, I want a singe .bat file and your answer below was very helpful. Finally, I used the `powershell -command` and used the `;` properly to seperate my `if` statement. However, I wonder if there is a way to make the code easier to read by displaying it as many lines instead of one somehow.

Comment: Sorry for the double, but I forgot to mention that I was speaking for a way to do that apart from the "encode" way.

Comment: You could do tons of echo to create a temporary `.ps1`-script file that you run with `-File`. Delete it when done.

Comment: Hmm okay. Thank you for your help, I think I will go with the one-line command.

Comment: See [dostips article](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=5526&start=15) for a much better example of incorporating properly formatted PowerShell code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `;` after every statement/linebreak (not curly-braces). Also, you could simplify the if/else.

```
PowerShell.exe -Command "& { $a = $false; if ($a -eq $false -or $b -eq $false) {'FALSE'; exit } }"
```

or encode it with Base64 and use `-EncodedCommand` like:

```
$command = @'
$a = $false

If ($a -eq $false)
{
    "FALSE"
    exit
}
Else
{
    If ($b -eq $false)
    {
        "FALSE"
        exit
    }
}
'@

$bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($command)
$encodedCommand = [Convert]::ToBase64String($bytes)
```

`$encodedCommand` will include the Base64-encoded string that you would use in a batch-file.

Demo:

```
powershell.exe -encodedCommand "JABhACAAPQAgACQAZgBhAGwAcwBlAA0ACgANAAoASQBmACAAKAAkAGEAIAAtAGUAcQAgACQAZgBhAGwAcwBlACkADQAKAHsADQAKACAAIAAgACAAIgBGAEEATABTAEUAIgANAAoAIAAgACAAIABlAHgAaQB0AA0ACgB9AA0ACgBFAGwAcwBlAA0ACgB7AA0ACgAgACAAIAAgAEkAZgAgACgAJABiACAALQBlAHEAIAAkAGYAYQBsAHMAZQApAA0ACgAgACAAIAAgAHsADQAKACAAIAAgACAAIAAgACAAIAAiAEYAQQBMAFMARQAiAA0ACgAgACAAIAAgACAAIAAgACAAZQB4AGkAdAANAAoAIAAgACAAIAB9AA0ACgB9AA=="
```